# class importance for random forest in r

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

I'm using `randomForest` pkg in R to predict the binary class based upon 11 numerical predictors. Out of the two classes, `Hit` or `Miss`, the class `Hit` is of more importance, i.e. I would like to know about how many times correctly predicted `Hit`.

Is there a way to give the `Hit` a higher importance in training the random forest? Currently the trained random forest predicts merely 7% of the Hit cases correctly and definitely would like an improvement.

Answer (score -1):

Higher importance?  I don't know how to tell any algorithm "I'm *not kidding* this time: I want this analysis to be accurate."

You're always fighting the variance versus bias battle.  If you improve the training accuracy too much, you run the risk of overfitting.

You can adjust random forest by varying the size of the random sample of predictors.  If you have m predictors, the recommendation for random forest is p = m^1/2 for the number of splits in the tree.  You can also vary the number of trees.  Plot the test classification error versus # trees for different values of p to see how you do.

You can also try another algorithm, like [gbm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf) (Generalized Boosted Regression Models) or [support vector machines](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html)

How does your data look when you plot it?  Any obvious groups jumping out at you when you look at them in scatterplots?

Regardless of algorithm, I'd advise that you do n-fold validation of your model.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'll go looking for additional predictors to add. Will look into GBM methods also. On a side note, is there a chance of over-fitting when current accuracy is only 7%? Also I want that the `Hit` class get higher weight. So as you are saying there is no way to do that in `rf`.

Comment: I used 5 fold cv in the current model, used `caret` pkg for that.

Comment: I don't think you need to add predictors; I'd adjust the knobs available to you in the algorithm.  I don't know how you're calculating the 7%, so I can't say.  I don't know what higher weight means.  What ratio of hit/miss points do you have in your training data set?  Maybe it's a data problem.